# Can't make "One To Many" relation work in Laravel

Tags: model, controller, eloquent, laravel-5, relation

this is my code in my Controller function :

```
$topic = Topic::create([
          'title' => $request->input('title'),
          'content' => $request->input('content'),
          'tags' => $request->input('tags'),
      ]);
      $forum = Forum::find($frid); // $frid = Forum ID
      $topic->myforum($forum->id);// Not working
      $topic->myforum($forum);// Not working
      $topic->myforum()->associate($forum->id);// Not working
      $topic->myforum()->associate($forum);// Not working
      $topic->myforum()->attach($forum->id);// Not working
      $topic->myforum()->attach($forum);// Not working
      $topic->myforum = $forum;// Not working
      $topic->myforum = $forum->id;// Not working
      $topic->creator()->attach(Auth::user()->id);//Same Here
      $topic->save();
```

Topic Model :

```
public function myforum()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('Forum', 'forum_id');
}


public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}
```

Forum Model :

```
public function topics()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Topic', 'forum_id');
}
```

User Model :

```
public function topics()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Topic', 'user_id');
}
```

So as you see in the controller I tried all the possibilities that I found on the internet and non of them have worked so please help with any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
return $this->hasMany('Topic', 'user_id');
```

we should use

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Topic', 'user_id');
```

Because even if we add the `use App\Topic;` it will not work and we have to make it like that